# Repetitively executing a macro in SaS

Tags: loops, macros, sas, proc-sql, do-loops

I am working with a dataset that in reality will have thousands of segments. For illustration I have enclosed 8.

What I am looking to do is to create a dataset for each segment so I can calculate the contribution of each dataset. I have done the majority of the work but what I am asking is to take every row of this output and turn it into its own dataset.

The data set looks like this

```
ID    Segment    Asset    Mapping    Performing    Fixed 

1     Loan       Asset    Loan1      Performing    Fixed
2     Loan       Asset    Loan1      No            Fixed
3     Loan       Asset    Loan1      P             Floating
4     Loan       Asset    Loan1      N             floating
5     Loan       Asset    Loan2      P             Fixed
...
8     Loan       Asset    Loan2      N             Floating
```

The Data is already nicely sorted as above.

The Macro I have written is as follows:

```
%macro BinData(i);

Data Bin&i;
set Import;
If _N_ = &i ;
run;

%mend;
```

Is there such a way to repetitively loop this macro for the (in the larger picture) all 8 (1000) segments, something like:

```
proc
do x=1 to 8;
%bindata(x);
run;
```

The importance is focused on creating a new segment for every row. TIA.

Comment: Presuming all the imports are same structured, you would be better off stacking all the imports in a single data set and adding one variable `source` to identify the origination.  After stacking you would work with `BY` and `CLASS` and `WHERE` statements instead of having thousands of datasets and needing to build a macro framework around those thousands.

Comment: Although this is technically possible this is a bad idea for several reasons but mostly because it's horrendously inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/* Your import data set */
data import;
    id=1;
    segment=1;
    output;
    id=2;
    segment=1;
    output;
    id=3;
    segment=1;
    output;
run;

/* Your macro to separate the rows into different data sets */
%macro temp;
    /* Create a list with all possible id's */
    proc sql noprint;
        SELECT DISTINCT id
        INTO :list separated by '#'
        FROM import
        ;
    quit;
    /* Create for each id a separate data set and output the rows into it */
    data
        %do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&list.,#));
            bin%scan(&list.,&i.,#) 
        %end;
        ;
        set import;
        %do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&list.,#));
            if _n_=&i. then do;
                output bin%scan(&list.,_n_,#);
            end;
        %end;
    run;
%mend;
%temp;
```

Comment: I've gone with a macro loop within a macro, lovely stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code:

```
%macro BinData;

%do i = 1 %to 8;

Data Bin&i;
set Import;
If _N_ = &i;
run;

%end;

%mend;

%bindata();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a non macro approach that splits according to a grouped variable, in this example, it's by age, but you can change it for ID. No looping and, in general, WHERE is faster than IF.

```
proc sort data=sashelp.class out=class;
by age;
run;

data _null_;
set class;
by age;
retain count;

if first.age then do;
    count+1;

    *create string;
    str1='data sub'||put(count,z3.)||"; set sashelp.class; where age="||put(age, 2.)||";run;";
    call execute(str1);

end;
run;
```